# Getting weird error with django: ORA-01843: not a valid month

Tags: sql, oracle, datatables

I am using `django 2.0.13` and I am connecting to an Oracle database with `cx_oracle`. The only thing I am trying to achieve is to pull data from a view and display it with datatable. I use django-datatables-view. But for a reason that I am unable to figure out about I am stuck with this issue.
Below is my sql request for creating the view.

```
create view V_SOLDE_FFTO_FTTH as
select distinct a.custid,client_name,code_cpt,c.categorie,round(b.solde) solde,suspendue,montant_gnf last_invoice 
from v_ftto_ftth a, v_solde_client_good b, v_facture_mois c
where a.custid = b.custid
and b.custid = c.custid 
order by 5 desc
```

Here is the result of this request:

[image]

And here is also the Django model I am using:

```
class SoldeFttoFtth(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'V_SOLDE_FTTO_FTTH'
        managed = False

    CUSTID = models.IntegerField(db_column='CUSTID')
    CLIENT_NAME = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column='CLIENT_NAME')
    CODE_CPT = models.CharField(max_length=200, db_column='CODE_CPT')
    CATEGORIE = models.CharField(max_length=100, db_column='CATEGORIE')
    SOLDE = models.IntegerField(db_column='SOLDE')
    SUSPENDUE = models.CharField(max_length=1, db_column='SUSPENDUE')
    LAST_INVOICE = models.IntegerField(db_column='LAST_INVOICE')
```

But when I try to access the view data with Django's ORM it get the following error:

```
django.db.utils.DatabaseError: ORA-01843: not a valid month
ORA-06512: at "LOG.DATECONVERTER_PLSQL", line 8
```

I have used two ways but none is working:

```
SoldeFttoFtth.objects.values('CUSTID', 'CLIENT_NAME', 'CODE_CPT', 'CATEGORIE', 'SOLDE', 'SUSPENDUE','LAST_INVOICE')
```

and

```
rows = []
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute("select *from V_SOLDE_FTTO_FTTH")
    for CUSTID, CLIENT_NAME, CODE_CPT, CATEGORIE, SOLDE, SUSPENDUE, LAST_INVOICE in cursor:
        rows.append({
            'CUSTID':CUSTID,
            'CLIENT_NAME':CLIENT_NAME,
            'CODE_CPT':CODE_CPT,
            'CATEGORIE':CATEGORIE,
            'SOLDE':SOLDE,
            'SUSPENDUE':SUSPENDUE,
            'LAST_INVOICE':LAST_INVOICE
        })
return rows
```

I am not getting the relationship between this error and my code since none of my model's fields has `datetime` or `date` as a type.

Comment: what is the `DATECONVERTER_PLSQL`? looks like the problem is there and not in the view

Comment: Look into the 3 other views you have there (v_ftto_ftth, v_solde_client_good, v_facture_mois) and find where LOG.DATECONVERTER_PLSQL is being called.

Comment: When I access the view from Django's shell the first attempt fails but the second succeeds. Form the user interface it never works. It's kinda very weird